# Dynamic array of fixed size array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

How do you allocate an array comprised of fixed size array of floats ? 
I tried this:

```
float **sub_uvs = malloc(sizeof(float [2]) * size * size);
/* Seg. fault */
sub_uvs[0][0] = 0.3;
sub_uvs[0][1] = 0.4;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multidimensional arrays of variable size are still tricky. Several options:

1. Use an array of pointers to arrays. Use one `malloc` for the array of pointers, then loop over `malloc` to make each row-array. But, this is a whole different data structure.
2. Find a class providing memory management and multidimensional indexing methods. Perhaps Blender has one?
3. Use [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) or a similar complete math library.

Comment: yeah I though it might be possible to write something like this                 
`float **sub_uvs = malloc(sizeof( two floats ) * size * size);`, I will just use a struct instead.

Comment: @MacelaruTiberiu The problem is that `**` indicates an array of pointers to arrays but you're trying to use it as one multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to perform another, separate allocation for the second array, presumably using another call to `MEM_allocN`.  You will also have to free this memory separately, using whatever deallocation function the platform provides.

The memory representation will be completely different, so even if it is syntactically more convenient in some places, it could be difficult to make this work everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

or you can use following :)

```
float **a;
a = (float **)malloc(sizeof(float *) * size_row);

for(int i=0;i<size_row;i++)
{
    a[i] = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * size_col);
}
a[0][0] = 0.4;

printf("%f",a[0][0]);
```